# How to return searched value and display it to user C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I want to search for specific userinput and then find it and output it to user?
and i cant seem to view older written post only the most recent logg is able to show.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            List<string[]> logBook = new List<string[]> { };
            bool isRunning = true;

            switch (Choose)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Write a logg: ");
                    string[] logg = new string[2];
                    logg[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv ditt inlägg: ");
                    logg[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                    logBook.Add(logg);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Write search word: ");
                    string searchWord = Console.ReadLine();
                    bool find = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < logBook.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (logBook[i].Contains(searchWord))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(logBook[i]);
                            find = true;
                        }

                    }
                    if (!find)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Couldnt find anything!");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: `logBook` is list of string arrays, you should look at every array to find the given value

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: Your code doesn't compile as is. `Choose` is not defined; you don't end your `Main` method or your `Program` class...

Comment: how do i look at every array without .Contains?

Comment: This will work, as long as the `searchWord` matches exactly an entire entry in the array. So if one of the arrays is `{ "good mojo", "bad mojo" }`, and `searchWord` is `"good mojo"`, this should find that and echo `"good mojo"` to the console. However, if you're expecting to use `"mojo"` as `searchWord`, it won't find anything.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PKEgEt3e this is my full code and still cant get older loggs.

Comment: @AbbasIbrahim did you see the answer?

Comment: Sorry about that yes i did and now it works,THANK YOU! is it possible to do this without .Contains?

Comment: @AbbasIbrahim, I'm not entirely sure about your requirements, but another way to find something in a string is with [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: How to use linear search in my case? thats really what im after and cant get it to work. Searching using comparison operators

Comment: can someone help me with linear search and comparison operator search? my code:https://pastebin.com/PKEgEt3e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the switch statement only:

```
switch (Choose)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Write a logg: ");
                        string[] logg = new string[2];
                        logg[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Skriv ditt inlägg: ");
                        logg[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                        logBook.Add(logg);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Write search word: ");
                        string searchWord = Console.ReadLine();
                        bool find = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < logBook.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                            {
                                if (!find && logBook[i][j].Contains(searchWord))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(logBook[i][j]);
                                    find = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!find)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Couldnt find anything!");
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

There must be an outer loop that asks for choices (1 or 2), otherwise your code runs only once.

The part you were missing was looking into the array itself in the list.